# Limit of a composite function when $f(x)^{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

Sorry but I really can't understand how to show this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: $g$ goes to $+\infty$ ?

Comment: I assume so that is all the information I was given

Answer (score 3):

When $x$ in a neighborhood of $a$ (small enough)  $g(x)>0$ and also $f$ so $Log(f^g)=gLog(f)$ goes to $-\infty$ then $f^g$ goes to $0$ ?

Comment: Why would ()  go to −∞?

Comment: $g$ goes to $+\infty$ and $log(f)$ goes to $Log(0^+)=-\infty$

Comment: oh ok, true. Then what about the example I gave in my answer?

Comment: Is that wrong somehow?